# How do I forward request to another proxy server using TIdHTTPProxyServer (proxy chain)

Tags: delphi, proxy, c++builder, indy

currently I want to make my indy proxy server forward the request to another proxy server. I have found [this link](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=151) and made a try by myself. But my code does not work without any error message as if I had made no change. My code is as below in C++ XE2.

```
void __fastcall TForm3::MyProxyHTTPBeforeCommand(TIdHTTPProxyServerContext *AContext)
{
    TIdIOHandlerStack* tempIO = new TIdIOHandlerStack(NULL);

    TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy* tempProxy = new TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy(NULL);
    tempProxy->Enabled = true;
    tempProxy->Host = "localhost";
    tempProxy->Port = 8181 ;
    tempIO->TransparentProxy  =  tempProxy;
    AContext->OutboundClient->IOHandler =  tempIO;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found I did something stupid. The correct code should be as follow...

```
void __fastcall TForm3::MyProxyHTTPBeforeCommand(TIdHTTPProxyServerContext *AContext)
{
    TIdIOHandlerStack* tempIO = new TIdIOHandlerStack(AContext->OutboundClient);

    TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy* tempProxy = new TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy(AContext->OutboundClient);
    tempProxy->Enabled = true;
    tempProxy->Host = "localhost";
    tempProxy->Port = 8181 ;
    tempIO->TransparentProxy  =  tempProxy;
    AContext->OutboundClient->IOHandler =  tempIO;
```